# Auto update using AJAX

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I have developed an application using Ajax/PHP to automatically display MYSQL records. My worry is, I have set AJAX to always check mysql database every 10 seconds, from a bandwidth perspective, do I have any case to answer? If yes, what's the best solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> - [Comet ( Programming )](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29)
> - [PHP jQuery AJAX Javascript Long Polling](http://blog.perplexedlabs.com/2009/05/04/php-jquery-ajax-javascript-long-polling/)
> - [JQuery PeriodicalUpdater (AJAX long polling/server polling)](http://enfranchisedmind.com/blog/posts/jquery-periodicalupdater-ajax-polling/)

also here is another responce about `AJAX` and `Chat` implementation that should treat pretty the same behaviours

> - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5234336/advanced-jquery-ajax-books-or-tutorials-online/

Comment: Exactly what am looking for. Much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

this comet reference my lead you in the right direction http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29